# Unexpected red brackets highlight in vim

Tags: c++, vim

In my C++ code vim shows red highlighted brackets in the following piece:

[image: vim screenshot]

This is some in-built functionality as I tried removing .vimrc, but it still shows them red. What's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the error shown by vim?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors. I mean, spellcheck, clang etc are switched off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim has only very limited C++ syntax highlighting capability built in. There is currently no support for C++11.

But there are, of course, plugins! Here's one that makes the error go away:

> [**C++11 Syntax Support:** A port of the existing C++ syntax to allow for C++11 features](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3797)

To install, download the archive and extract the files into your `~/.vim/syntax` directory. Enable the C++11 file type with `:setf cpp11` or follow the instructions on the plugin home page.

Comment: Thanks, will try it and report back.

Comment: Does this work for C (ie: using C11) as well? Thank you.